# InterBase database blob column

Tags: interbase

Could anyone please tell me how can I display the contents of an InterBase database blob column. I am trying to display the column in plain text or display its content but cast doesn't convert the data type. BLOB SUB_TYPE 0 SEGMENT SIZE 80

Comment: This makes sense, since a blob type isn't plain text, but rather a bunch of bytes.
you'll need to do the conversion yourself before you can display it (in whichever form).
Blob leaves the type of data you're handling up to the developer, so long as you can convert it to and from a byte array.
Which language are you using btw?

Comment: Not using any language just plain Interbase sql. The data subtype is 0 by the way.

Comment: I've seen that I need to use a BLOB filter. I made one but not sure if it works. How can I call a blob filter in a InterBase query?